# Using webhook sending message to telegram from wordpress?

Tags: wp-remote-request

I want send a message to telegram whenever a form submitted. i am using gravity form plugin form. and it has the hook

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
```

which will be call after form submitted. and i create a telegram bot and submit my url as webhook url base on instruction.
here is my code:

```
$url = $path."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$userID."&text=".'messaginggggg';
$request = file_get_contents($url);
```

the problem is when i use the url in my browser it perfectly send notification to my bot , but from the site it returns error :

```
Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed out in (my file path) line 20
```

line 20 is : $request = file_get_contents($url);

Comment: Where is `$userID` coming from?

Comment: its actually uniqe id of my account in telegram

Comment: @JacobPeattie the url works correctly on my browser, but file_get_contents can not access the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an internet problem. i couldn't send a message from my site because of filterning probelm. Telegram is ban in my country then i should change the server to use Telegram.